# match data and copy/paste macthed and unmatched data in two different sheets

Tags: excel, vba

i got a data input in sheet1 and sheet2 which gets compared. If there is line(s) in sheet1 that match line(s) in sheet2, then copy and paste the whole line to first possible row in sheet3. It needs to match in column C, D, E, H and I to be a totally match. If everything but column H match, then copy/paste line(s) to sheet4 and state the difference in column H.

So my data is set to have 2 matches and 2 amount differences. The 2 that match is fine in sheet3, but the 2 that doesn't match is the problem, as only one of the lines is shown in sheet4.

Can anyone help me please :)

Code so far:

```
  Sub MatchRows()
      Dim a As Variant, b As Variant, c As Variant, d As Variant
      Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, m As Long, n As Long
      Dim dic As Object, ky As String

      Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
      a = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:I" & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(3).Row).Value
      b = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:I" & Sheets("Sheet2").Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(3).Row).Value
      ReDim c(1 To UBound(a, 1), 1 To UBound(a, 2))
      ReDim d(1 To UBound(a, 1), 1 To UBound(a, 2))

      For i = 2 To UBound(b, 1)
          ky = b(i, 3) & "|" & b(i, 4) & "|" & b(i, 5) & "|" & b(i, 9)
          dic(ky) = i
      Next

      For i = 2 To UBound(a, 1)
          ky = a(i, 3) & "|" & a(i, 4) & "|" & a(i, 5) & "|" & a(i, 9)
          If dic.exists(ky) Then
              j = dic(ky)
              If a(i, 8) = b(j, 8) Then
                  k = k + 1
                  For n = 1 To UBound(a, 2)
                      c(k, n) = a(i, n)
                  Next
                  c(k, 8) = 0
              Else
                  m = m + 1
                  For n = 1 To UBound(a, 2)
                      d(k, n) = a(i, n)
                  Next
                  d(k, 8) = a(i, 8) - b(j, 8)
              End If
          End If
       Next
       If k > 0 Then Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).Resize(k, UBound(a, 2)).Value = c
       If m > 0 Then Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2).Resize(m, UBound(a, 2)).Value = d

       Sheets(3).UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
       Sheets(4).UsedRange.Columns.AutoFit
  End Sub
```

Comment: `d(k, n) = a(i, n)` you probable should be using `m` not `k`.Same here `d(k, 8) = a(i, 8) - b(j, 8)`

Comment: Copy the data to two sheets, sort each sheet (one for criteria existing, one for not) and delete hidden.

Comment: Will try that CDP1802 ! And Cyril can you give an example of what you are saying?

Comment: IT WORKS! Man you saved my day. Then @CDP1802 do you know how to make all lines green in the match sheet (sheet3) and all red in sheet4?

Comment: @CDP1802 have a new question with a different data input, hope you can help, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69220260/vba-match-rows-in-sheet1-sheet2-and-show-matched-in-sheet3-and-unmatched-in-sh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To color the cells set [Interior.Color](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.interior.color) property.

```vb
    Dim rng as Range
    If k > 0 Then
        Set rng = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        With rng.Resize(k, UBound(a, 2))
            .Value = c
            .Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0) ' green
        End With
    End If

    If m > 0 Then
        Set rng = Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        With rng.Resize(m, UBound(a, 2))
            .Value = d
            .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' red
        End With
    End If
```

Comment: Thanks! Have a great day